# C# TabControl binding with linq groupby statement in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, group-by

I am new to WPF and I am trying to bind a List of grouped object to a tabControl and I just manage to get halfway there

Here is my C# Code In the constructor :

```
IEnumerable<Validation> validations = ReflectiveEnumerator.GetEnumerableOfType<Validation>().Where(validation => validation.IsActive);

tabControl.ItemsSource = validations.GroupBy(validation => validation.TabName);
```

and my xaml code is :

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="10,10,10,37" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValidationName}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

and so I get a tab by group which is what I was expecting  but within my wrap panel I only have 1 ValidationName per Tab, I was expecting multiple ones. what is missing to have the content panel Iterate through my group.

When I don't group by I have multiple tabItem with the same Name and that's not what I'm looking for.

My Validation class looks like :

```
public class Validation
{
    public string ValidationName {get; private set;}
    public string TabName{get; private set;}
    public bool IsActive{get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: P.S. Sorry for my English, it's not my first lanquage

Comment: A groupby is going to create a two dimensional object : <TabName, List<Validation>>.  So you need to enumerate through the List<Validation>.

Comment: how to do this in xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ItemsControl in the ContentTemplate of the TabControl:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="10,10,10,37" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValidationName}" Margin="10"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The above sample markup will display a TextBlock per item in each group in a WrapPanel inside each TabItem.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you